# MRv1 and MRv2 parameters

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, mrv2

Entire list of parameter( for Hadoop-2.6) is given on the [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

But you can execute a job in either  MRv1 or  MRv2 style. I think there are some parameters that are only applicable for MRv1 like `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum`,
is this true ? If yes, then is there any smarter  way to figure out all such parameters ?
can we pass all parameters via -Dproperty=value or -D property=value or  is there any parameter, that i can not pass like this ?

Answer (score 1):

In MR2, the number of map tasks will be calculated dynamically by resource manager depending on the memory assigned to the each container.

**From hortonworks**

With YARN and MapReduce 2, there are no longer pre-configured static slots for Map and Reduce tasks. The entire cluster is available for dynamic resource allocation of Maps and Reduces as needed by the job

**This page has got more info. check this** http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/

You can pass any parameter using -D property = value from command line. There is no restriction on that. But if these properties are set in code by developer, the command line property will be overidden by job.

Comment: is there any smarter way to figure out all such parameters  ?

Comment: you can check mr1 and correspondin mr2 properties here . http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_mapreduce_to_yarn_migrate.html